# Spring Batch MultiReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to for multi-read using spring batch approach in which i have to get  result from multiple queries and need to do some processing withe result and write them into file. I tried for a sample code but its giving me a error. I believe i have almost there but something i am missing due to my limited knowledge in spring batch

Below is my Code

MultipleReader-batch-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:context-datasource.xml" />

<!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" />

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id= "result1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" >
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="sql" value="SELECT * from SNG_CORE.LOOK_UP" />
<property name="rowMapper"> <bean class="com.websystique.springbatch.ExamResultRowMapper" />
</property> 
</bean>

<bean id ="result2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" >
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="sql" value= "SELECT * from SNG_CORE.LOOK_UP_2"/>
<property name="rowMapper"> <bean class="com.websystique.springbatch.ExamResultRowMapper" />
</property> 

</bean>

<bean id="customItemReader" class="com.websystique.springbatch.MyCustomReader" scope="step">
<property name="result1" ref="result1" /> 
<property name="result2" ref="result2" />
</bean> 

<job id="MultipleReaderJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
<step id="step1">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="customItemReader" writer="flatFileItemWriter"
            commit-interval="1" />
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

```
    <property name="resource" value="file:csv/examResult.txt" />

    <property name="lineAggregator">

        <!-- An Aggregator which converts an object into delimited list of strings -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">

            <property name="delimiter" value="|" />

            <property name="fieldExtractor">

                <!-- Extractor which returns the value of beans property through reflection -->
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names" value="studentName, studentName1, studentName2" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

====

## ExamResultRowMapper

```
public class ExamResultRowMapper implements RowMapper<ExamResult>{

    @Override
    public ExamResult mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        ExamResult result = new ExamResult();
        result.setStudentName(rs.getString("I_LKUP"));
        result.setStudentName1(rs.getString("C_LKUP_TYP"));
        result.setStudentName2(rs.getString("C_LKUP_KEY"));

        return result;
    }
```

==================

## Custom Reader

```
public class MyCustomReader implements ItemReader<ExamResult> {

ItemReader<ExamResult>  result1;
ItemReader<ExamResult>  result2;

@Override
public ExamResult read()
        throws Exception, UnexpectedJobExecutionException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {


ExamResult application1 = result1.read();
ExamResult application2 = result2.read();
    /***
     * I want to perform some operation with two result set 
     * and passs the final data to writter
     * /

    ExamResult summary = new ExamResult();

    return summary;
}

}
```

===Exam result===

```
public class ExamResult {


    private String studentName;
    private String studentName1;
    private String studentName2;



    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }



    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }



    public String getStudentName1() {
        return studentName1;
    }



    public void setStudentName1(String studentName1) {
        this.studentName1 = studentName1;
    }



    public String getStudentName2() {
        return studentName2;
    }



    public void setStudentName2(String studentName2) {
        this.studentName2 = studentName2;
    }




@Override
    public String toString() {
        return " [studentName=" + studentName + ", dob=" + studentName1 + ", Std=" + studentName2 + "]";
    }


}
```

====================================================================

When ever i execute this i am getting 
Encountered an error executing step step1 in job MultipleReaderJob

## org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.customItemReader' defined in class path resource [MultipleReader-batch-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'result1' of bean class [com.websystique.springbatch.MyCustomReader]: Bean property 'result1' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Note : All works good if i run my job to read with 1 result set .

```
<job id="MultipleReaderJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
<step id="step1">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="result1" writer="flatFileItemWriter"
            commit-interval="1" />
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

Comment: What is `MyCustomReader` supposed to do if we give it 2 `JdbcCursorItemReader`? Can you share its code? Is it an option for you to use SQL unions (something like `SELECT * from SNG_CORE.LOOK_UP UNION SELECT * from SNG_CORE.LOOK_UP_2`) if it is supported by your rdbms? Otherwise you can try to use an intermediate table where you load data from both tables then do the work on the intermediate table.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud for the reply .  You are right I can certainly do union . I was trying for multiple reader option , if it works i have certain complex logic needs to be processed based on the data from two result set. Let me ping you the code here

Comment: Mahmoud , I just Plugged my code here. For your information , My intention is to read result set from both beans together and do some processing..

Comment: I'm not sure that's the right approach.. How about opening/closing each cursor? You need to implement `ItemStream` too. What if one cursor returns more data than the other, how to handle this case? Which key you would put in the execution context in case of restart? `You are right I can certainly do union`: if that's possible, a single jdbc reader with a single query that does the union is a better approach IMO.